# Ajax post with jQuery datepicker not showing date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a datepicker in my form and I would like to post the form data with an ajax call. My problem is that the form does not get the date selected from the datepicker.

Here is the link to the theme I am using with the datepicker:
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB00U99JJ

Here is the html for the datepicker which is inside the form:

```
<div id="datepicker-inline" name="date"></div>
```

Here is my ajax post

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('form');
    var date = $('#datepicker-inline');
    $.ajax('/api/service', {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Success!");
            $('#status').addClass('status-bar-success');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('OH NOES!');
            console.log(form.serializeArray());
            console.log(date.val());
            $('#status').addClass('status-bar-error');
        }
    });
});
```

I am running in the console to see what I get. The form.serializeArray() is working and the date.val() gets the date selected. My quesion is how do I had the date value into the form.serializeArray()?

*** UPDATE ***

html

```
<div id="datepicker-inline"></div>
<input type="text" id="date_hidden" name="date added" class="no_show"/>
```

ajax

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('form');
    var date = $('#datepicker-inline').val();
    $('#date_hidden').val(date);
    $.ajax('/api/service', {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Success!");
            $('#status').addClass('status-bar-success');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('OH NOES!');
            console.log(form.serializeArray());
            console.log(date);
            $('#status').addClass('status-bar-error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have a `name`? (Edit: Oh now it has)

Comment: @Kuma I added the name field, but still no luck. The ajax call completely skips over the datepicker.

Comment: Try to inspect the generated html on that div, forms don't submit non-input elements.

Comment: @Kuma there is no input in the entire datepicker... It is made up of divs, a, spans, and a table.

Comment: @Kuma if you look at the theme link I posted above you can see the datepicker

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, I'm afraid he can't modify the HTML generated by bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `hidden` element alongside that `div` since it doesn't have any `input` element.

```
<div id="datepicker-inline" name="date"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker-inline_hidden" name="date"/>
```

And in your submit you could do

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('form');
    var date = $('#datepicker-inline');
    $('#datepicker-inline_hidden').val(date);
    //... your code
```

So that your date value is submitted as the `hidden` element.

Comment: I had to update one small part of your code. Please see my above update. Thanks!